# angularJS: Function in function

Tags: angularjs

Hello I'm new in angularJS. Suitable or not to implement function inside function?

For example like this:-

```
$scope.loadDistrict = function(id) {
  // statement
  $scope.loadBasedOnYear = function(y_id) {
    console.log(y_id);
    // statement
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you bind method on scope, it's available from view.

From your code

```
$scope.loadDistrict = function(id) {
  // statement
  $scope.loadBasedOnYear = function(y_id) {
    console.log(y_id);
    // statement
  };
};
```

`loadBasedOnYear` won't available until `loadDistrict` is called.

It's very bad pattern to follow.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but without context I don't really know why you would do this, calling `$scope.loadBasedOnYear` before calling `$scope.loadDistrict` will result in an error so be careful with such a design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is fine.

You should watch out for when the function will be executed outside of angular's cycle. E.g. if you do:

```
setTimeout(function() { $scope.test = 5; }, 1000);
```

If you need to do this then you need to wrap the function in $scope.$apply(), or use $timeout.